# issues with sysdate in sqlplus

Tags: sql, sqlplus

```
create Table dealing_record(
dealing_record_id int NOT NULL,
Transaction_number Varchar (6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Number_of_shares Number NOT NULL,
Amount Number (7,2) NOT NULL,
Stamp_duty Varchar(6) NOT NULL,
commission Varchar(6) NOT NULL,
Date_time SYSDATE     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(dealing_record_id));
```

outcome

```
 SQL> create Table dealing_record(
2  dealing_record_id int NOT NULL,
3  Transaction_number Varchar (6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
4  Number_of_shares Number NOT NULL,
5  Amount Number (7,2) NOT NULL,
6  Stamp_duty Varchar(6) NOT NULL,
7  commission Varchar(6) NOT NULL,
8  Date_time SYSDATE     NOT NULL,
9  PRIMARY KEY(dealing_record_id));
Date_time SYSDATE     NOT NULL,
      *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Please what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Date_time SYSDATE     NOT NULL,
```

should be

```
Date_time date      NOT NULL default SYSDATE,
```

Sysdate is a value, not a datatype.

Comment: how do i get the time aswell? I tried DATETIME but got errors.

Comment: In oracle, the date datatype consists of both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is not a data type. You probably mean

```
Date_time DATE     NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

SYSDATE is not a data type. Replace with "DATE". Im not sure but I think you can also add "DEFAULT SYSDATE" on the end if you want to default with the current date/time.

Answer (score 0):

SYSDATE is not a data type at all. So you will get that error on any tool.

```
CREATE TABLE DEALING_RECORD ( DEALING_RECORD_ID INT NOT NULL,
                            TRANSACTION_NUMBER VARCHAR ( 6 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                            NUMBER_OF_SHARES NUMBER NOT NULL,
                            AMOUNT NUMBER ( 7, 2 ) NOT NULL,
                            STAMP_DUTY VARCHAR ( 6 ) NOT NULL,
                            COMMISSION VARCHAR ( 6 ) NOT NULL,
                            DATE_TIME DATE NOT NULL,
                            PRIMARY KEY ( DEALING_RECORD_ID ) );
```

Comment: how do i impliment both date and time

Comment: this is nothing but both data and time. Try to insert with SYSDATE as value.